# Dart - First letter of each word in a List

Tags: list, dart

```
List<String> pisah = ['saya','sedang','belajar','menjadi','programmer','yang','handal','dan','menyenangkan'];
```

How can I make that list so that I can print just every first letter of the word
example like :

baris 1 : S S B M P Y H D M

Answer (score 1):

That's all in a day's work for the method [`map`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Iterable/map.html).

```
  final letters = pisah.map((s) => s[0]).toList();
  print(letters);
```

The `.toList()` call may or may not be needed depending on what exactly you want to do with the result. For example, it can be omitted if you want only to iterate over it, but it's required if you need to access individual letters using `letter[i]`.

Comment: Thanks sir,  for helping me and correcting my poor grammar xD